# Printing the HTML of a website with c++/php?

Tags: php, c++, html

I've been wondering, is there any way to print out the HTMl code of a website using c++ or php code? IF there is, I'd be glad if you could provide me with some materials to read and/or perhaps some codes would be perfect :)

and also, can we send a javascript command to that website using c++/php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print file_get_contents("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308228/printing-the-html-of-a-website-with-c-php");
```

print the source:

```
 print htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308228/printing-the-html-of-a-website-with-c-php"));
```

please explain regarding the js command, what do you want to do?

Comment: thanks! that was fast! file_get_contents can also be parsed to strings right? and about the js command, can we send anything through port 80 to the other end? any command would do good.. I hope its clear enough

Comment: the other site should expose an api for that. you cant inject js commands. dont forget the the entire thing is happening in your browser and wont affect other users, or else it will be considered xss hack(cross site scripting)

Comment: file_get_contents return a string (html in your case), if you want the content in the html use: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php (or parse it as xml)

Comment: ah im sorry i wasnt clear enough. the website itself is already equipped with bundles of javascript functions, my question was, can we call a function (already defined) with c++ or php?

Comment: OK, no, javascript is happening in the client, meaning it will have to run from a proper browser. for what you want, you should look for a server side api from their side

Answer (score 2):

If you are on a *nix system, you could use something like this in C++

```
char buf[2500];
size_t size;
FILE *remote_file = popen("curl http://www.example.com/index.html", "r");
do {
    size = fread(buf, sizeof(char), 2500, remote_file);
    fwrite(buf, sizeof(char), size, stdout);
} while(2500 == size);
```

Or you can do this with PHP

```
print file_get_contents("http://www.example.com/index.html");
```

---

Your last question

> can we send a javascript command to
>   that website using c++/php?

doesn't make any sense. JavaScript is entirely client-side. You don't send JavaScript commands to a server.